# JavaScript DOM for Sever Side Variables

Tags: javascript

I am using Server Side variable as `<%=value01%>` and I need the a JavaScript function to be done if `value01` is an email address. I have written a JavaScript in the below way which is not working. Anybody please correct it.

```
    var myem = document.getElementByTagName('value01').value;

    if(myem.value.match(/[.].*[@]|[@].*[.]/))
    {
        alert('Value contains email');
    }
```

Comment: For javascript server-side see node.js and for a DOM sever-side see jsdom (https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) but I don't think this is what you actually need :)

Comment: Be careful, you use twice `.value` and this is `getElement*s*ByName('value01')[0]`

Comment: @cheeken - Not PHP, I am using ASP.NET

Comment: @Morre - I don't think this needs node.js

Comment: @sinsedrix - Great observation. But still there are more errors with this code :(

Comment: @Mad coder: I already said so myself, didn't I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a hidden input or preferably use the HTML5 `data-` attributes:

```
<input id="interestingElement" type="hidden" value="<%=value01%>" /> // Hidden input
<div id="interestingElement" data-email="<%=value01%>" /> // data- attribute
```

Javascript:

```
var email = document.getElementById('interestingElement').value;  // Hidden input
var email = document.getElementById('interestingElement').attributes['data-email']; // data- attribute
if (email.match(yourEmailRegex ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should look like this:

```
/^[\w_\.\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.+[\w]+$/
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want validate all kinds of emails (both .com or .com.xx) this regex will works:

/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/

To try:

```
var myem = document.getElementsByTagName('value01').value;
var emailRegex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

if(emailRegex.test(myem))
{
    alert('Value is a email');
}
```

Comment: It doesn't match `my+address@domain.museum` wich is a valid email.

Comment: @leohackin - My question doesn't need Regex. I have issue with `document.getElementsByTagName('value01').value;`